# Distinguish smart card readers of the same type

Tags: windows, winapi, setupapi

I have an app that uses a smart card reader. A user may have several identical readers, and their system names, as returned by `SCardListReaders`, differ in number suffix, for instance "OMNIKEY CardMan 5x21 **0**" and "OMNIKEY CardMan 5x21 **1**". User can set up the the reader for the app. If during work user puts the smart card in another reader the app will not react.

The problem is, I have reports that after the Windows restart the readers can be shuffled as well. The one that had "**0**" in the name before can now have "**1**". I have no influence on this. After the shuffle happens the user must choose the reader again in the app, and I want to fix this somehow so that user does not have to do anything.

First I was toying with `SCardGetAttrib` and `SCARD_ATTR_VENDOR_IFD_SERIAL_NO`, but this parameter does not return a unique string for every reader in the world. For instance it may return "12345678" for all readers of the same certain type.

I am now looking at SetupAPI function `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty`. I can list all USB devices, and parameters `SPDRP_PHYSICAL_DEVICE_OBJECT_NAME` and `SPDRP_LOCATION_PATHS` seem to be unique and I hope fixed in the system. If reader is not a USB device then I'll rely just on the name, as I am now. Problem is, I can't deduce from reader name which USB device I should be looking at. None of the `SPDRP_` parameters will give me a reader name, and I need the name that I can give to `SCardConnect`.

How can I get from reader name to corresponding `HDEVINFO` that I can give to `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty`? Alternatively, is there another way to distinguish between smart card readers of the same type, which is reliable even after Windows restart?

Comment: If the user has multiple readers, why limit the user to a specific reader? You can monitor the readers (see `SCardGetStatusChange()` and `SCardLocateCards/ByATR()`)  to detect reader state changes and follow a card as it moves from one reader to another. Does `SCardGetReaderDeviceInstanceId()` allow you to differentiate readers? What about the device number provided by `SCARD_ATTR_CHANNEL_ID` from `SCardGetAttrib()`?

Comment: Can't use `SCardLocateCards` because several cards of the same type can be inserted at the same time in different readers, but I am only interested in one of them. Can't use `SCardGetReaderDeviceInstanceId` because I have to support Windows XP (but Vista solution is also welcome). `SCARD_ATTR_CHANNEL_ID` gives the same value for all readers (0x200000).